# Can't get tensorflow on Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I need tensorflow to run a guided project I did on Coursera, but I am not able to install it.
This is the screenshot of trying to install from Anaconda Navigator:
[Anaconda Nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0agz.png)

I checked on the official website of Anaconda to check if it is available, and it shows that it is available for python 3.8:
[Anaconda Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDTc.png)

I have also tried installing with the command on the website, and this is the error it shows:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBFxT.png)

I am new to this and would appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the error message in the question itself instead of adding a link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error, it looks like you have installed a 32 bit version of anaconda. For 32 bit installations, I cannot find any `tensorflow` package files in the default channels.

Simply uninstall the 32 bit version, then download and install the 64 bit version from [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86_64.exe)

Then you should be able to install `tensorflow` using the anaconda navigator or the command line

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I installed anaconda 64-bit on my computer, but it doesn't open. I tried clicking on Anaconda Navigator, Spyder, etc. but nothing happens at all. I have a 64 bit version of Windows 10, and I have 24GB ram. Can you please help me identify the problem in this?

Comment: can you try running a conda command in the anaconda command prompt? For instance, try running `anaconda-navigator` or also simply `conda info`

Comment: I solved the problem by uninstalling RStudio. I guess that was causing some problems. and finally installed tensorflow as well. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Otherwise, you can use `pip install tensorflow`.  Pip should already be installed if you've installed python